# kinect camera with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, camera

I'm working with my graduation project and I should submit the work after 2 month limited time to know all the new stuff. Please can anyone can help me with these questions?

My project is about authentication with brain signals and face for face. I bought a kinect camera for windows and I am struggling to connect it and show it in asp.net. All the samples and examples deal with WPF.

Can anyone help me with:

1. How I can show the camera in asp.net
2. Any help about authentication with face recognition only one person each time via kinect camera?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: ASP.NET is not allowed to access hardware on the client. It might be possible through ActiveX/Silverlight.

Comment: Please fix the wording of your question, it is hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Besides Silverlight & ActiveX there are two possible ways you can try to connect your Kinect with a web application:

1. The [Kinected Browser](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/kinectedbrowser/) project has an JavaScript API that allows you to connect IE to the Kinect.
2. The [Kinect SDK 1.8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kinectforwindows/archive/2013/09/17/updated-sdk-with-html5-kinect-fusion-improvements-and-more.aspx) has support for HTML 5 including samples for interacting with HTML.